# Java Makefile Parser alternatives

Tags: java, makefile

Are there any alternatives for [Java Makefile Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/makefileparser/) library?

I might need a Java library to parse make files in order to extract some information or even simulate execution in given environment. A quick look up suggests that there is only the Java Makefile Parser. But maybe I didn't look in the right places. So is there any other library?

Note that I'm not stating that there is anything wrong with Java Makefile Parser. I haven't even tried it yet. I only want to know my options.